# Uncaught SoapFault exception:

Tags: php, webservice

Buen dia, muchachos estoy tratando de hacer un llamado a un web services y que me devuelva unos parametros pero al momento de ejecutar el php me genera este error

> atal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SoapClient::SoapClient(): $wsdl must be string or null in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMBULANCIAS\AMBULANCIAS_P2\webService.php:37 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMBULANCIAS\AMBULANCIAS_P2\webService.php(37): SoapClient->SoapClient(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMBULANCIAS\AMBULANCIAS_P2\webService.php on line 37

el problema es que según la documentación los parámetros están bien y si realizo la prueba con el programa SOAP Ul funciona correctamente, el codigo con el que realizo el proceso es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include("./nusoap/lib/nusoap.php");
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);
define("DEBUG", TRUE); 
if (DEBUG) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

$directorioWSDL = "WSSISPOS_serviciosINCAPAC_SAP.wsdl";
$wsdl = 'https://preesb.compensarsalud.com/esb.preproduccion.consorcio/WSSISPOS_SERVICIOSINCAP_SAP_serviceagent?wsdl'; //URL de nuestro servicio soap

$params = array(
    "sApl" => "SWPR75",
    "sParams" => '<![CDATA[<INC><PARAMS><APLICACION>SWPR75</APLICACION ><CODIGO>53136070</CODIGO><CODEPS>008</CODEPS><TIPO>1</TIPO><FINIINC>20050101</FINIINC><FFINAL>20191230</FFINAL><OPCION>4</OPCION></PARAMS></INC>]]>'
     );
 

$options = array(
    "url" => $wsdl,
    "style" => "SOAP_RPC",
    "use" => "SOAP_ENCODED",
    "soap_version" => "SOAP_1_2",
    "cache_wsdl" => "WSDL_CACHE_BOTH",
    "connection_timeout" => 15,
    "trace" => false,
    "encoding" => "UTF-8",
    "exceptions" => true

);

//Enviamos el Request
$soap = new SoapClient( $options); 

$vem = $soap->__call('ConsultasIncapacidades', array($params));
var_dump($vem);
echo file_get_contents($vem);
```

**EDITO:** Al cambiar la línea que instancia el cliente de acuerdo a las respuestas,

```
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

me sale este otro error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://preesb.compensarsalud.com/esb.preproduccion.consorcio/WSSISPOS_SERVICIOSINCAP_SAP_serviceagent' : failed to load external entity "https://preesb.compensarsalud.com/esb.preproduccion.consorcio/WSSISPOS_SERVICIOSINCAP_SAP_serviceagent" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMBULANCIAS\AMBULANCIAS_P2\webService.php:43 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMBULANCIAS\AMBULANCIAS_P2\webService.php(43): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://preesb....', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMBULANCIAS\AMBULANCIAS_P2\webService.php on line 43

---

Gracias Alfabravo  colocando el codigo  con el que me ayudaste me genera el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://preesb.compensarsalud.com/esb.preproduccion.consorcio/WSSISPOS_SERVICIOSINCAP_SAP_serviceagent' : failed to load external entity "https://preesb.compensarsalud.com/esb.preproduccion.consorcio/WSSISPOS_SERVICIOSINCAP_SAP_serviceagent" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMBULANCIAS\AMBULANCIAS_P2\webService.php:43 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMBULANCIAS\AMBULANCIAS_P2\webService.php(43): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://preesb....', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMBULANCIAS\AMBULANCIAS_P2\webService.php on line 43

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde recuerdo -*y según la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)*-, en PHP ese cliente WSDL tiene dos parámetros, la URL del WSDL y el array de parámetros:

```
public SoapClient::SoapClient ( mixed $wsdl [, array $options ] )
```

Así pues, te falta indicarle la URL del servicio a consumir y por eso se está quejando.
Podrías usar entonces en tu código:

```
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

**Edito**: Para el otro error, yo me guiaría por las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875409/soap-php-fault-parsing-wsdl-failed-to-load-external-entity) y revisaría que:

- Tu servidor con PHP puede validar el certificado del servidor donde está el webservice. Esto se lograría añadiendo `openssl.cafile=C:/path/to/sslCertificates/cacert.pem"` al php.ini. **Cambiando la ruta por la ruta correcta al cacerts de tu instalación SSL** (vas a encontrar varias versiones.. la de Java, la de OpenSSL... cualquiera debe servir mientras esté actualizado el software correspondiente).
- o deshabilitando la validación SSL (no es tan buena idea, debería funcionar sin ésto, pero para efectos de *prueba y debug* puede servir

  ```
  $opts = array(
   'ssl' => array(
      ...
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false
   )
  );
  ```
- Revisando que el certificado en el servidor donde está el webservice sea o no autofirmado (no expedido por una autoridad certificadora pública como Symantec, komodo o similar, sino generado por quienes mantienen el servidor). Si es así, vas a necesitar una opción diferente en los parámetros

  ```
  $opts = array(
   'ssl' => array(
      ...
      'allow_self_signed' => true
   )
  );
  ```
- deshabilitando el parseo de los entities antes de invocar el web service, poniendo esta línea de código por encima de todo lo que tienes ahí

  ```
  libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
  ```
- Revisando que tu configuración de PHP pueda abrir recursos externos (en el php.ini también)

  ```
  allow_url_fopen -> 1
  ```